# Drawing rectangles and oval

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

First sorry if my question was asked before (i had search but couldn't find answer)
here is the question:
I wanna draw rectangle and oval when user type 1 or 2. I am programming with JAVA and here is my code.

```
package shapes;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class shapes extends JPanel 
 {
    private int choise;
public shapes (int userchoise) 
{
choise=userchoise;
}
public void paintcomponent (Graphics g)
{
  super.paintComponent(g);
  for (int i=0; i<=10; ++i)
{
switch (choise)
{
case 1 :
g.drawRect(10+i*10, 10+i*10, 50+i*10, 50+i*10);
break;
case 2:
g.drawOval(10+i*10, 10+i*10, 50+i*10, 50+i*10);
break;

        }
    }
}
}
```

this is the main class:

```
package shapes;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class shapestest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String input= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter 1"
            + " to drawing rectangel"+"Please enget 2 to drawing oval");
    int choise = Integer.parseInt(input);
    shapes myshape=new shapes (choise);
    JFrame application = new JFrame();
    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    application.add(myshape);
    application.setSize(300, 300);
    application.setVisible(true);


}
}
```

The problem is I can't see anything when i run the program (after type 1 and 2)

How do I solve this problem?
....
Guys I finally found how to solve the problem (thanks to [@kiheru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2471439/kiheru)

The only problem that this code have is just about case sensitive: `paintcomponent`  is not the same thing as `paintComponent`  `public void paintcomponent (Graphics g)`. So if you do this change, the code will work.

Comment: Please include your code not as jpg, but as text withing your post (marked as code) so that others can directly work on it. You'll get quicker answers that way.

Comment: Class names should start with an upper case character. Posted code should be formatted properly. I'm sure you don't write code left justified, so don't expect us to read code like that.

Comment: sorry I'm new on this. But trying to make it better thanks for remind that to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void paintcomponent (Graphics g)
```

Use `@Override` notation before this method declaration. That will reveal a compilation error.

To fix it, use upper case for `Component`:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
```

Comment: I did that but not working (get me back this error: The method paintcomponent(Graphics) of type shapes must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: *"he method paintcomponent(Graphics) of type shapes must override or implement a supertype method"* The journey of a thousand miles begins with a single step. The 2nd step is to try and understand what that error means, then how to fix it. Time for some searching..

Comment: Look **very carefully** at the 2nd paragraph (starting *"To fix it.."*) and code snippet.. (note that the answer expanded over a few minutes time when I first posted it).

Comment: I did that but still not work. the prime error was gone and still not working!

Comment: Is that possible that the problem was about my software, not code? I'm using Eclipse and using windows 10.

Comment: Works fine for me. Repost your updated code showing the changes your have made and with the proper indentation. Also. add a System.out.println() statement to your painting method to display the "choise" to make sure you are executing the changed code. This is basic debugging.

Comment: *"Is that possible that the problem was about my software, not code?"* Your code is broken, and I can see that by just reading it!